# Get orderBy value in ng-repeat directive from element attribute?

Tags: angularjs

So I have this directive:

```
app.directive('replaceelement', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope:true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.blockcss = attrs.blockcss;
            scope.sorter = attrs.sorter;

        },
      template:'<div class="{{blockcss}}" ng-repeat="content in something | limitTo:10 | orderByPriority | orderBy:sorter"  ng-include src="blockcss+\'.html\'"></div>'

    }
});
```

Nothing too special.

This is the element it should run on.

```
<replaceelement blockcss="cssname" sorter="sortby"></replaceelement>
```

I run a simple ng-click to change the variable called sorter in my controller.

Orderby does not work with the sorter attribute. I have a *feeling* that its because sorter is a variable in the controller, and I cant call it by the name passed from the attribute?

Been working on this all day and cant find a way to do it. Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a plunker? It will help alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the orderBy in the ng-repeat works exclusively with arrays. See here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Comment: Is there a way for me to convert a string to an array inside the link: function?